# Rails: Uniqueness validator not respecting scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I ran into this issue and wanted to post this so that way others don't spend so much time banging their head against a wall like I did.

---

I have a `User` model. On the `User` model, I have `uniqueness` validate on the `email` attributed scoped to its `type` attribute. See below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :email,
    uniqueness: {
      scope: :identifier
    }
end
```

However, the `UniquenessValidator` doesn't respect the fact that `email` uniqueness validator is scoped to its `identifier` attribute.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was happening:

*Devise*'s `validatable` module overrode my `uniqueness` validator for `email`. Simply removing this module allowed me to validate my email's `uniqueness` scoped to its `identifier` attribute.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # removed :validatable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable


  validates :email,
    uniqueness: {
      scope: :identifier
    }
end
```